# How to receive a SMS on phone with a ticket number through Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, twilio-twiml

I have created an agent on Dialogflow like a help desk, While making a service request the user enters his phone number.At the end of the conversation the bot says "you'll receive your ticket number via SMS on your entered mobile number".

How do I make it so that I received a text on my mobile number through Twilio with a random ticket number ?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I believe that in Dialogflow if you want to run some code in response to an intent then you need to setup [fulfillment using a webhook](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/tutorials/build-an-agent/create-fulfillment-using-webhook). That way you can build a webhook that uses the [Twilio API to send the SMS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages) and then responds with the message "you'll receive your ticket number via SMS...".

The Dialogflow docs on [fulfillment via webhook has a tutorial on how to build this out](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/tutorials/build-an-agent/create-fulfillment-using-webhook). I would recommend reading through that and implementing your own fulfillment webhook.